# Laravel migration constraints syntax error

Tags: mysql, laravel, database-migration

I'm trying to run php artisan migrate command, but I'm getting an syntax error for every constraints like unique, index etc. Posted error is from default unchanged create_users_table migration, because it's first migration to process. When I delete this unique constraint from email column, I get same error for another constraint in next migration. I think there could be mistake in 'devices unique' shown in error message. It should be 'add unique'.

Error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'devices unique `users_email_unique`(`email`)' 
at line 1 (SQL: alter table `users` devices unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))


[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'devices unique 
`users_email_unique`(`email`)' at line 1
```

Migration

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->string('name');
  $table->string('email')->unique();
  $table->string('password');
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Project
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:jRIQ9RxhMYRK9UJXgme1KlA6bd1rA0OGyK96SdBP1nI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://project.dev

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do not post a image of the error message. Post the error message in full as text. Also, show your code.

Comment: Ok sorry, I edited my post right way up.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it because the unique not suppo rt for 255 character varchar, you just only declare the email just 50 character

> $table->string('email', 50)->unique();

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting exactly same error again. If i remove unique constraint completely then I'm getting very similar error for index constraint on next migration of laravel create_password_resets_table. If i remove this index then I'm getting error for next unique on my next migration and so on.

Comment: can i see your .env

Comment: Sure, I added .env to the first post/question.